# How to fix Apache active (exited) error?

Tags: server, apache2, gui

I'm working on a project that requires using Apache Web Server, everything so far was working correctly until yesterday when I accidentally deleted the i3 package, the graphics driver and all of a sudden my GUI was lost, somehow I restored it but now Apache server doesn't seem to start, trying `sudo service apache2 status` says

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; generated)
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-05-26 11:58:35 IST; 1s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 4048 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 4064 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
May 26 11:58:35 <my_user_name> systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server
May 26 11:58:35 <my_user_name> systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web serve
```

Some more info that might help:

> I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with Dell Vostro 3268

It would really be appreciated if someone could help me find a way out of it.

Thanks, A lot in Advance

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it myself, in my case it turns out that I accidently messed up with `apache2.conf` file in `etc/apache2` so one of the things that can be done is to first delete your config files and then reinstall `Apache` again.

Steps:

Stopping `Apache` if already running with `sudo service apache2 stop`

Checking `Apache`'s status to confirm if it is stopped with `sudo service apache2 status`

Deleting the config files with `sudo apt purge apache2`

Removing `Apache` with `sudo apt remove apache2`

Reinstalling it with `sudo apt install apache2`

Setup your config files, and then try running the server again.